# how to write c++ webservice in linux machine using fast_cgi module where apache being the webserver

Tags: c++, web-services, apache

I am looking at writing c++ webservice for linux with apache being the webserver.i am working on linux for first time so i needed your help.

Am following the instructions given by Fast_Cgi site.

- I have downloaded the toolkit "mod_fast_cgi-2.4.6.tar.tar" from the site " http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/".
- Then i followed the instructions given in "INSTALL.AP2" file which is present in toolkit.
- I was able to generate “fast_cgi.so file”. Now this file is located in my  directory

#### Configuring httpd.conf

next step is to make changes in my

In http.conf file –

I have added "LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so" in the begining of the  httpd.conf file

then they have said to add these things before virtual host directive

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>

   FastCgiIpcDir /tmp/fcgi_ipc/

   AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi

</IfModule>
```

#### Sample C++ program

my test program "Testwebservice.cpp"  looks like this

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h" /* fcgi library; put it first*/
#include <stdlib.h>

int count;

void initialize(void)
{
    count=0;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Initialization. */  
    initialize();

    /* Response loop. */
    while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0)   {
        printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
                "\r\n"
                "<title>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</title>"
                "<h1>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</h1>"
                "Request number %d running on host <i>%s</i>\n",
                ++count, getenv("SERVER_HOSTNAME"));
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I feel am missing something in the  directive which i added just before the virtual host directive.

could you help me to know what am i missing here.

what is that i have to add in httpd.conf file which will direct the http requests coming to  the apache webserver to my c++ application.

Comment: I'd suggest mod_fastcgi although I'm a little unclear on the question - are you looking for running ISAPI dlls on Linux still? Or "the way I'd do it if I didn't have ISAPI as a constraint?"

Comment: I don't think you'll ever be able to run ISAPI DLLs on linux out of the box. ISAPI is very much IIS/Windows specific.

Comment: Why does this need to be written in C++? You are facing an uphill battle, certainly when it comes to the SOAP element alone. I think you need to be looking at a Java-based solution...